# Prove that $(e^x-\ln y)^2+(x-y)^2\geq 2$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Prove that $(e^x-\ln y)^2+(x-y)^2\geq 2,\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\forall
> y>0$. When does the equality hold?

I note that the equality holds only if $x=0,y=1$, but I don't know how to prove that without using functions with two variables. Any hint?

Comment: Why do you believe that you can solve it without calculus of several variables?

Comment: @Siminore I don't know. It should be solvable using only calculus of one variable (such as MVT, derivatives, integrals, etc.), since it is included on a Greek textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the facts 
$$\begin{align}e^x &\geq 1+x\\
\ln y &\leq y-1
\end{align}
$$
Then
$(e^x-\ln y) \geq (2+x-y)$.
Now you have 2 cases.

1. $(x-y+2)<0$. Then $(x-y)<-2$ and $$ (e^x-\ln y)^2+(x-y)^2 \geq (x-y)^2 \geq 4 \geq 2.$$
2. $(x-y+2)\geq 0$. Then
   $$ (e^x-\ln y)^2+(x-y)^2 \geq (x-y+2)^2+(x-y)^2.$$
   Here substitute $x-y=k$ and you obtain
   $$(k+2)^2+k^2=2k^2+4k+4.$$
   At this point you can easily prove that this quantity is always greater or equal than $2$.

---

For the equality, observe the proof. It can holds only if $2k^2+4k+4=2$. This holds if and only if $k=-1$, i.e. when $x-y=-1$. Now substitute it in your expression. You have
$$e^x-\ln(1+x)=1$$
It should be easy prove that the only solution is $x=0$, by observing that $e^x>1+x$ for every $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following identity: for $\forall x,y\in(0,\infty)$,
$$(e^x-\ln y)^2+(x-y)^2=(e^x-x)^2+(\ln y-y)^2\color{red}{+}2(x-\ln y)(e^x-y).\tag{1}$$
Due to the monotonicity of $e^x$, we have
$$(x-\ln y)(e^x-y)=(x-\ln y)(e^x-e^{\ln y})\geq0.\tag{2}$$
By $(1),(2)$, we get (also use $e^x-x\geq1,y-\ln y\geq1$)
$$(e^x-\ln y)^2+(x-y)^2\geq(e^x-x)^2+(\ln y-y)^2\geq1+1=2.$$
When $x=1$ and $y=0$, the equality is ture!

Comment: @ River Li Thank you ! I fixed it.